# Efficient Way of Adding Objects to Inherited Class List

Tags: class

I was learning a bit about classes because I never actually covered up the topic too much and never knew a lot about it since I'm a beginner and I wrote a small program just to practice a bit and I was wondering if there is a more efficient way of adding class instances like students into a list of students, sorry for the stupid title and not a very clear description but I will copy the code here so it's more clear

```
class Student:

    def __init__(self, name, grade, major, is_smart: bool):
        self.name = name
        self.grade = grade
        self.major = major
        self.is_smart = is_smart

    def get_grade(self):
        return self.grade

    def get_major(self):
        return self.major


class ComputerScience:

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.students = []

    def add_student(self, student):
        self.students.append(student)


s1 = Student('Denis', 91, 'Computer Science', True)
s2 = Student('Julia', 81, 'Electronics', False)
s3 = Student('John', 56, 'Gender Studies', False)
s4 = Student('Mark', 88, 'Computer Science', True)
s5 = Student('Lora', 96, 'Medicine', True)
s6 = Student('Lucy', 99, 'Computer Science', False)


computer_class = ComputerScience('Majors')
computer_class.add_student(s1)
computer_class.add_student(s2)
computer_class.add_student(s3)
computer_class.add_student(s4)
computer_class.add_student(s5)
computer_class.add_student(s6)

for student in computer_class.students:
    print(student.name + "'s major is " + student.major)
```

My problem was with this part:

```
computer_class.add_student(s1)
```

I think there's gotta be a more efficient way of adding the students to the list,

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What do you mean by "more efficient"? What would you like to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to have a variable for each Student object, so you can add a student like this:

```
computer_class.add_student(Student('Denis', 91, 'Computer Science', True))
```

If you have lots of student objects, it is better to read them from a file.